# How to add a character ',' in Django for loop template?

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have a Django for loop like this:

```
{% for i in file %}{{ i }}{% endfor %}
```

Somtimes file contains only 1 data which is fine in the case. But if the file contains more than one data I want to show the data like this:

```
If three data
ok, ok1, ok2.

If only one data.
ok.

If four data:
ok, ok1, ok2, ok3.
```

I tried adding `{% for i in file %}{{ i }}, {% endfor %}` but it shows comma for the last file too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#join):

```
{{ file|join:", " }}.
```

Comment: Problem with this, first it does what I wanted but after that it join and simply display.

Comment: @user2032220: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Data looks like this: ok, ok1, ok2. okok1ok2

Comment: @user2032220: The filter does what it's meant to do. If your data is displaying like that, it's a problem with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for i in file %}
    {{ i }}
    {% if forloop.last %}
    .
    {% else %}
    ,
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Blender's answer is best though.